# Slow Apache response time on high performance server

Tags: php, apache, time, response, httpd.conf

My server enviroment: CENTOS 6.5 x86_64, apache 2.2.27 with prefork module with PHP 5.2.17 (cli). and this server for 1 streaming video site (like youtube) and i have problem with Apache response time and i think the problem with httpd.conf file. so anybody can help me to config Apache?

SERVER SPECS:

- Intel Xeon 2x E5-2650v2
- Cores/threads: 16c/32t
- Frequency/burst: 2,6 GHz+/3,4 GHz+
- RAM: 128 GB DDR3 ECC 1600MHz
- Hard disks: 3 x 2 TB SATA3 6 Gbps with Hardware RAID 5 (MegaRAID LSI 9271-4i CacheVault 1 GB)
- Guaranteed bandwidth: 500 Mbps

currently apache configured as follows:

- Start Servers 5
- Minimum Spare Servers 5
- Maximum Spare Serves 10
- Server Limit 8192
- Max clients 4800
- Max Requests per Child 10000
- Keep-Alive Timeout 5
- Max Keep Alive requests 100 default
- Timeout 300 default

I use a suphp PHP 5 Handler and Apache suEXEC is On.

the website receives about 40-60k visitors daily (120-180k Impressions/day)

Apache response time becomes slow when Online users becomes more than 200,

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you think the problem is in your conf file why did you post everything but your conf file?

Comment: @carter Because httpd conf file with default values, I have changed only Server Limit to 8192 and Max clients to 4800.

Comment: @user3121348 No one can help you, if you will not POST your information.  We know it takes time and effort.  We only want to help you and depend on you for providing the information requested to make assistance be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use below tools to fine tune your server

Apache:

```
https://github.com/richardforth/apache2buddy
```

Mysql:

```
https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl
```

Furthermore I sugegest you to offload your static contents to cdn (images.js.css), as they might be eating your webserver. Use gzip compression and do static assets caching as well. Perform a scan of your site on below tools to see response time for requests.

```
webpagetest
gtmetrix
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your website slows down because of a database limitation? If you say with 200 users, it looks like a default limit of MyŚQL.

Are you sure it is related to apache?

If you somewhere not close the connections in a good way, it can run out of connections